# How can i navigate (e.g. open Mozilla) in a Remote Desktop by using java code written in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, remote-desktop

I want to be able to open Mozilla Firefox in a Remote Desktop and be able to "play" inside Mozilla (accessing URLs, import from the "Desktop" of the Remote Desktop Connection). All these, I want them to be automatically executed. That is why I have created a java code in eclipse. So far, I am able to automatically access the Remote Desktop Connection. Please find the code that I am using for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String ip = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";    //check if this is the desired IP
    String userName = "XXX";        //check if this is the correct username
    String password = "XXXxxx";     //check if the password has changed
    String jacobDllVersionToUse;
    jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-x64.dll";

    File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse);
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    // creating credentials
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmdkey /generic:"+ip+" /user:"+userName+" /pass:"+password );
     p.destroy();    

     Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mstsc /v: "+ip+" /f /console");

     AutoItX x = new AutoItX();      
     x.winWaitActive("Remote Desktop Connection");
     x.controlClick("Remote Desktop Connection", "Co&nnect", "1");
     x.winWaitActive("Remote Desktop Connection");
     x.controlClick("Remote Desktop Connection", "Co&nnect", "1");
}
```

Could you assist me on how I will be able to open Mozilla in Remote Desktop through eclispse?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the code successfully activates the RDP Window. 
Once it is active AutoIt can't identify elements controls inside the window, but you can still send keyboard commands using Java Robot or even AutoIt. 
To launch Firefox send a Window+R and then pass the path of firefox.exe ("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe") and send ENTER.

Comment: I continue the code with: 
`x.send("#r");
 x.send("firefox.exe"); (it would work also without the path)`
but nothing happens. Meaning the Run is not appearing in Remote Desktop.

Comment: Try clicking inside the window before sending #r. I tried this manually and simply activating the RDP window and sending Window+r doesn't launch Run unless I click inside the RDP window

Comment: Even with the proposed way, again I am not able to enable this functionality. By performing a digging on the Internet, I found that in order to be able to use the send function, I need to run it as an administrator. Since I am not the administrator, is there any other way to perform the above?